# touching objects from mutable array

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have created some buttons and I keep them in NSMutableArray.

In the view where they appear there are a few simple sdk methods to handle touches.

The problem is touching exactly this objects from MutableArray and nothing else.
Here is method touchesBegan:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (isEarthquake == NO) {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            UIButton *menuButton;
            menuButton = [menuButtons objectAtIndex:i];
            if (CGRectContainsPoint([menuButton frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])) {
                [self startTouchTimer:3.00];
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

isEarthquake is simple bool that checks if action can be performed.
after that I want to check all objects if they are being touched.

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touches began is a view method, not a view controller method. You are using 
    locationInView:self.view
this should be
    locationInView:self

Check this code is in a view subclass and not a view controller subclass.

Also, you might need to use 
    [self convertRect:[menuButton bounds] fromView:menuButton];
to convert the CGRect to the proper coordinate space.

Comment: try logging the frames and points with NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:buttonFrame]); and NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGPointt:touchPoint]);